# Postgresql extension not enabled in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

I have a postgres table with a polygon column called shape. In order to determine if a point is inside I run

```
select * from areas where shape @> point '(1,1)';
```

this is all fine and working in my ruby on rails app, but it fails in my RSpec test. When I look at my logs I find this error as source

```
 PGError: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying @> point
 HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

All other 50+ tests using the DB work, just this one bails. And again it works in the code and in the console.  The test environment is all properly set up.

My question: 
- How can I cast the comparison subjects to work? 
- And why would it fail only in test?

Comment: Are you accidentally using a different type of database (e.g. mysql) for your test environment?

Comment: @DavidGrayson: `PGError` indicates PostgreSQL so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: >Do you have all the necessary PostgreSQL extensions loaded in your test database?
I don't do anything specific for that. Its a simple geometric type that doesn't require any extension to my knowledge.

Comment: select * from areas where polygon(shape) @> point '(1,1)';

The polygon cast fixed it. Then I found that in my test database the column shape was string. Thats why it was complaining about shape. So I dropped my db, ran rake db:dump to create schema.rb and my polygon type is string again. How can I make it aware of polygon? In the database the column certainly polygon.

Answer (score 5):

By default activerecord uses schema.rb to keep the test database in sync with your development database. Schema.rb is database independant (it uses the same constructs as migrations) but the flipside is that it doesn't tend to support all the bells and whistles that a database may have, especially one like Postgres which adds a lot of extra stuff.

You can set `config.active_record.schema_format` to `:sql` instead which will use the database's own tools to produce a .sql file that rails will lose instead of schema.rb. You'll lose the ability to run your tests against a different db, but if you're using postgres  specific extensions then you're in that scenario anyway.

Another possibility would be to enhance active record's schema dumper to understand polygon columns. The foreigner gem adds foreign key support to schema.rb for example

Comment: I found this workaround. Run rake db:test:clone_structure. And run the tests with just "rspec" and not "rake spec" since this will always regenerate the structure and is much slower anyways. So this kinda works.

Answer (score 1):

That error seems to suggest that the `shape` column is defined as a varchar. Check to be sure it's a polygon.

```
\d areas
```

Comment: in my development environment its a polygon, verified that again. When I run rake db:schema:dump and look at the schema.rb its classified as an ordinary string again.